# Clicking current date in asp.net calendar control doesn't fire selectionchanged event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar

I am sorry if this a duplicate question but I can't seem to find an answer.

This is the problem. I have as asp page with a calendar control on it. I have two text boxes below it. When I click a date it puts the date in the box. My problem is if I try to click the current date, nothing happens. The Calendar selection changed event doesn't trigger.

This is how i am putting the date in the text boxes (Probably not the best way)

```
    If DateRange1.Text = "" Then
        DateRange1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()
    Else
        DateRange2.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()
    End If
```

If I click any date other then today's date it works fine. How can I get the current date to enter either text box when clicked on the calendar

Comment: The reason this isn't working for you is because when you select today, the calendar is not changing.  You could set the current selection with the on click event.

Comment: Sorry but I still new, so what event would I wire up to put the date in the text box no matter what date is selected then?

Comment: It should be the On_Click event. But you can look through the events, they are usually self explanatory for when they fire.

Comment: I can not find an On_Click event for the calendar and when I try to add it I get an error.

Comment: Got it. I moved the If statement to the page load event and it works now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Well it didnt work as i expected. It would only add the current date no matter what date you click on. So i am back to square one.

Comment: Ok so I Do have it figured out. In the page load I had the following: Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today. By taking this out i am abl to select any day including the current date.

Comment: In Page Load, `Calendar1.SelectedDate = Nothing` works too.